# How to get all rich:dataTable values using javascript when rich:dataScroller is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, datatable, richfaces

I have a `<rich:dataTable>` and implemented pagination using `<rich:dataScroller>`

```
<rich:dataTable id="myTable" rows="5" rowKeyVar="rowVar" value="#{Bean.collectionInBean}" var="myVar">
<!--Table Data-->
</rich:dataTable>
<rich:dataScroller for="myTable" />
```

When not using the  data scroller (I don't use the `rows` attribute in the data table either when not using the scroller) I can select all of the the values in a column of the table using jQuery to select elements using the `id` of the column's cell content. So if I have a column of `<h:inputText id="myInput" value=#{myVar.inputReceiver} />` I can loop through all of them and let's say get their values using:

```
var elements = $("[id*='myInput']");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  var value = elements[i].value;
  //do whatever with value
}
```

But once I use the `<rich:dataScroller>` the only values returned are the ones that are on the page that is currently selected. Is there a way to get all of them while still using `<rich:dataScroller>`?

Comment: You should accept Makhiel's answer. It's correct (and Makhiel is a RF developer, so he's probably sure:D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. The purpose of the component is to show only a portion of the data at a time.